# Best way to delete a user related model record

Tags: delete-row, eloquent

This is how i am deleting a record,can you please suggest me what is the best approach to delete a record.

```
        public function delete_post($id) {
        //Check if id is numeric and exists
        if( (is_numeric($id)) && (!empty($id)) )
        {
            $post = Post::find($id);
            // check if this id belongs to user (User has author)
            if(Auth::id() == $post->user_id){
               Post::with('likes')->whereId($id)->delete();
            }else{
                Session::flash('error', 'You can't delete this.
            }
        }else{
            Session::flash('error', 'Problem with your input');
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your delete into a transactions

More in here:
[Laravel Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions)!

Comment: Yes we can wrap this in transactions as well,but i need best way to delete user record.